# MySQL Timed out when starting server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection-timeout

So i was working on a login system with MySql. At first it worked perfectly, but after a bit of time it stopped working and now when I start it it gives me

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (I:\Websites\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:409:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:484:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (I:\Websites\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (I:\Websites\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (I:\Websites\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (I:\Websites\backend\Main.js:20:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

What is also important to say is that I do not host the Database on my PC, I have rented a server for it. Hope that someone can help

Comment: `ETIMEOUT` means your database server machine is unreachable over the network from the machine running your nodejs code. Is a firewall in the way? Are you attempting to connect to a private IP address on the database machine rather than a public IP address?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.